# Wordpress permalinks GET and POST report url 404 while I can access the URL from browser

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, nginx

I have NGINX server with added code on `location/` in the configuration file for the website. I have the latest versions of WordPress and WooCommerce.

The problem exists even if I change the theme (default) and deactivate all plugins except WooCommerce. When permalinks are at default (eg. `www.example.com/?page_id=5`) everything works fine; I can add and update products in cart.

If I change permalinks to a "nicer" format (eg. `www.example.com/cart/`) although I can access the page `www.example.com/cart/` through the browser, in the console I get the following:

> GET http://www.example.com/cart/ 404 (Not Found)
>   Navigated to http://www.example.com/cart/

When I try to add or update products by pressing add to cart or update cart buttons, in cart product page or cart page nothing happens and console reports the error.

Can anyone suggest me where to start digging?

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    # server_tokens off;
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    # gia 504 gateway time-out fix
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;

    #pros8esa mpas kai lisi to 502 bad gateway
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;





    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##
    #log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        #               '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
        #               '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';
   #log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
      #                     '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
      #                     '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';
log_format        main '"$remote_addr" $host [$time_local] '
                  '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                  '$request_length $bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" $request_time "$gzip_ratio"';

  #  server {
   #     gzip on;
   #     access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log compression;

   # }

    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log compression buffer=32k;
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;
    access_log off;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;



}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

site-enable file

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
    listen 80; #default_server;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri$args =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }


    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #


location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }


    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
    #sef url

}
server {
    server_name  example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.example.com$1 permanent;
}

# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#   ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: Would you please update your permalink and after check it?

Comment: what do you mean ? when I try to access through permalinks url I have chosen "nicer" permalinks from general settings in wp-admin

Comment: I mean GO TO `setting > permalink` and update your permalink.

Comment: Permalinks are updated. I set common settings to post-name and product to default .

Comment: 404 means the resource location is not available. You need to check from where this is originated. From NginX or from the actual backend. The NginX configurations might help. So please share

Comment: I have edit the question, added nginx config and site config files. how I can start searching where is the error originated from? Because it strange that although it says page not found (file not found) it actually nagivated to that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your `try_files` statement. It should be:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri$args;
}
```

Or (what I use):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

The `try_files` directive can only have one default. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.